# Factory pattern with 4 layer architecture

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In my project i have 4 layers presentation,BL,DL, and dataObjects. i want to implement abstract factory pattern to get the object i want(doctor/Engineer). Is  the code below implementing factory pattern?

```
 public interface IProfessional //The Abstract Factory interface. 
{
    IProfession CreateObj();
}

// The Concrete Factory  class1.
public class DocFactory : IProfessional
{
    public IProfession CreateObj()
    {
        return new Doctor();
    }
}

// The Concrete Factory  class2.
public class EngFactory : IProfessional
{
    public IProfession CreateObj()
    {
        // IMPLEMENT YOUR LOGIC
        return new Engineer();
    }
}
// The Abstract Item class
public interface IProfession
{       
}

// The Item class.

public class Doctor : IProfession
{
  public int MedicalSpecialty
 {
  get; set; 
 }
  public int AreaofExpertise
 { 
  get; set; 
  }

}
// The Item class.
public class Engineer : IProfession
{
  public string Title{
     get;set;
}
  public int AreaofExpertise 
{ 
 get; set; 
}


}


// The Client class.
public class AssignProfession
{
    private IProfession _data;

    public AssignProfession(DataType dataType)
    {
        IProfessional factory;
        switch (dataType)
        {
            case DataType.Doc:
                factory = new EngFactory();
                _data = factory.CreateObj();//from here i will get engineer

                break;
            case DataType.Eng:
                factory = new DocFactory();
                _data = factory.CreateObj();//from here i will get doctor

                break;
        }
    }

    public IProfession GiveProfessional()
    {
        return _data;
    }
}

//The DataType enumeration.
public enum DataType
{
    Doc,
    Eng
}
```

Comment: Yep, It seems to... Besides that, why do you need to be sure? the purpose of the patterns is to solve problems. If the design solves your problem, then it's ok.

Comment: I will agree with @ivowiblo, read this article as well http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/are-you-pattern-happy/

Comment: i know little about design patterns. it is solving my problem..as i am first time using it thts why want to confirm.

Comment: @shalini please fix your switch statement, there's a logical bug. you are creating Eng against DataType.Doc and Doc against DataType.Eng

Answer (score 1):

Your code does implement the pattern but not to the full extent which C# allows, in other words - you are not using the important benefits of the C# language.

Here is an example of how you can do it better:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myEngineer = ProfessionFactory.CreateProffession<Engineer>();
        var myDoctor = ProfessionFactory.CreateProffession<Doctor>();
        myEngineer.EnginerringStuff();
        myDoctor.HealingPeople();

        var myEngineer2 = (Engineer)ProfessionFactory.CreateProffession("Engineer");
        //using the other method I still have to cast in order to access Engineer methods.
        //therefore knowing what type to create is essential unless we don't care about engineer specific methods,
        //in that case we can do:
        var myEngineer3 = ProfessionFactory.CreateProffession("Engineer");
        //which is useless unless we start involving reflections which will have its own price..
    }

    public interface IProfessionFactory
    {
        IProfession CreateObj(); 
    }

    public interface IProfession : IProfessionFactory
    {
        string ProfessionName { get; }
    }

    public abstract class ProfessionFactory : IProfessionFactory
    {
        public abstract IProfession CreateObj();

        public static T CreateProffession<T>() where T:IProfessionFactory, new()
        {
            return (T)new T().CreateObj();
        }

        public static IProfession CreateProffession(object dataObj)
        {
            if (dataObj == "Engineer")
                return CreateProffession<Engineer>();
            if (dataObj == "Doctor")
                return CreateProffession<Doctor>();
            throw new Exception("Not Implemented!");
        }
    }

    public class Engineer : IProfession
    {
        public string ProfessionName
        {
            get { return "Engineer"; }
        }

        public IProfession CreateObj()
        {
            return new Engineer();
        }

        public void EnginerringStuff()
        {}
    }

    public class Doctor : IProfession
    {
        public string ProfessionName
        {
            get { return "Doctor"; }
        }

        public IProfession CreateObj()
        {
            return new Doctor();
        }

        public void HealingPeople()
        {}
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just at a glance, but having a Doctor inherit from a ProfessionFactory doesn't sound right.

Comment: Doctor is both a profession and a little factory to create doctors.
Acutally I'll revise as any profession is also a profession factory.

Comment: IMO, the statement "this class is two things" (a profession, and a factory) is a bit of a smell, and tends to indicate that it doesn't follow the single responsibility principle.

Comment: @Mathias the alternative is having a factory class that is able to return new of any profession which inflict to seperation of concerns. so in one side I agree the SRP rule is broken, but I prefer to break SRP rule than to break SOC rule. putting this to the side, i think it's a matter of angle, I can claim that this class is doing one thing: it handles a profession, or I can claim it do 3 diffrent things. if it has not reptitive code and it follow SOC it is good. imo SRP is more of a guideline to achieve SOC.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to have all elements of the pattern, however your IProfession is empty. I am going to assume that is just a placeholder and you are going to fill it in with some methods that represent a behavior that is common to all professions.
Contrast that with the example given in Allen Holub's [book](http://www.holub.com/goodies/patterns/)
He mentions Collection as the AbstractFactory, Iterator as the abstract product, Tree as the concrete factory and the iterators that are returned as concrete products.